# SELECT FROM depending on a parameter in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures

I want to obtain from a parameter, `@Display` the value 0, 1 or 2. When @Display = 0, I want to display all the items for which `ec.IsEquipmentRelated` is true. When @Display = 0, I want to display all the items for which `ec.IsEquipmentRelated` is false and when @Display = 2, I want to display all the items for which `ec.IsEquipmentRelated` is true *OR* false. How can I implement this in the `FROM` section?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Downtime_GetNewCause_EquimentLocation]
    @DisplayInactive bit = 0,
    @SortOrder INT = 0,
    @Diplay INT = 0
AS

-- Main Data source
SELECT    ic.IncidentCauseID
        , 'EquimentRelated' = COALESCE(ec.IsEquipmentRelated, 0)
        , ic.NewIncidentCauseID
        , ic.DisplayName 
        , ic.IsLegacy
        , el.EquipmentLocationID
        , el.ShopID
        , ec.EquipmentClassID
        , ec.EquipmentAbbr
        , el.ClassSequenceNumber
        , el.EquipmentComponent
        , el.CompSequenceNumber
        , ic.IsActive
FROM    Downtime_IncidentCauses ic
        LEFT JOIN Downtime_EquipmentLocations el ON ic.EquipmentLocationID = el.EquipmentLocationID
        LEFT JOIN Downtime_EquipmentClasses ec ON el.EquipmentClassID = ec.EquipmentClassID AND
            CASE WHEN @Diplay = 0 THEN ...
            CASE WHEN @Diplay = 1 THEN ...
            CASE WHEN @Diplay = 2 THEN ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
INNER JOIN Downtime_EquipmentClasses ec 
ON (el.EquipmentClassID = ec.EquipmentClassID)
    AND (  (@Display = 0 AND ec.IsEquipmentRelated = 1) 
        OR (@Display = 1 AND ec.IsEquipmentRelated = 0) 
        OR (@Display = 2) )
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to put that in the outer join.

Comment: It would be interesting to see a performance comparison between the two.  The specific question was how to put it in the "FROM" section, though.

Comment: Exactly, and the `LEFT JOIN` is in the `FROM` section.

Comment: It doesn't work with an outer join. It has to be an inner join so that the records from all tables are included in the join.

Answer (score 1):

Do it in a `WHERE` clause:

```
WHERE (@Display = 0 AND ec.IsEquipmentRelated = 'True')
OR (@Display = 1 AND ec.IsEquipmentRelated = 'False')
OR @Display = 2
```